# Formatting a Numpy array with even and odd numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator, format

I am trying to write a code that replaces the even numbers with positive `init_val` value within the `sequence_numbers` and every odd and 0 valued variable into negative `init_val` values. How would I be able to code such a thing?

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

sequence_numbers= np.array([1,0,4,7,9,12,15,16,22,2,4,8,11,13,11,21,23,3])

#The choice could be 'even', 'odd' or '0'
choice = 'even'
init_val = 100
```

Expected output:

```
[-100, -100, 100, -100, -100, 100, -100,100, 100,
 100, 100, 100, -100, -100, -100, -100,  -100, -100 ]
```

Comment: So you didn't try anything or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.where` and the modulo operator to determine the odd/even status.

Example for 'even':

```
out = np.where(sequence_numbers%2, -init_val, init_val)
```

output:

```
array([-100,  100,  100, -100, -100,  100, -100,  100,  100,  100,  100,
        100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100])
```

For 'odd', just reverse the True/False values:

```
out = np.where(sequence_numbers%2, init_val, -init_val)
```

or inverse the `init_val`:

```
if choice == 'odd':
    init_val *= -1
out = np.where(sequence_numbers%2, -init_val, init_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
out = (sequence_numbers % 2 * -2 + 1) * init_val
print(out)

# Output
array([-100,  100,  100, -100, -100,  100, -100,  100,  100,  100,  100,
        100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100])
```

Comment: I'd write it `(sequence_numbers % 2 * -2 + 1)*init_val` for clarity (only one variable then)